# Array input numbers 0-2 and output corresponding letters a,b,c

Tags: java, arrays, output

I have created the array with the elements ("A","B","C")
if the user enters ‘0’ output “A” to the outputlabel,e.g.,outputLabel.setText(array[0]).

I am just getting errors in the command prompt when i enter in the correct numbers. Any help with this would be highly appreciated. I have the gui created correctly. Just unsure about the array and outputs.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class GuiFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

String[] stringArray = {"A", "B", "C"};
JTextField inputArea;
JLabel theOutputLabel;


public GuiFrame() {

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Please enter the index of the array to 
output: ");
    JLabel outputLabel = new JLabel("Array index");
    JTextField userInput = new JTextField ();
    JButton inputButton = new JButton("Go");
    String inputFromUser = userInput.getText();

    Container contentPane = getContentPane();

    panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(outputLabel);
    panel.add(userInput);
    panel.add(inputButton);

    inputButton.addActionListener(this);

    contentPane.add(panel);
    setSize(250, 250);
    setVisible(true);
    userInput.setSize(250,50);

    System.out.println(inputFromUser);

    String stringArray[] = new String[3];


  }


public static void main(String[] args){
    new GuiFrame();
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    String userInput = inputArea.getText();
try {
    do {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("0"))
            theOutputLabel.setText(stringArray[0]);
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("1"))
            theOutputLabel.setText(stringArray[1]);
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("2"))
            theOutputLabel.setText(stringArray[2]);
    }while(e.getActionCommand().equals("0") || e.getActionCommand().equals("1") || e.getActionCommand().equals("2"));

    System.out.println("You have entered a number that is outside of the range of the array index please try again");

    }

catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException arrayError){
    System.out.println("Array Index Out of Bounds");
    arrayError.printStackTrace();
     }

   }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have now defeats the purpose of using an array.  Imagine you had to do it for all letters of the Alphabet, would you add 26 conditions?  What if you have thousands of options?

Thererfore, instead of

```
    /** DON'T DO THIS */

    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("0"))
        theOutputLabel.setText(stringArray[0]);
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("1"))
        theOutputLabel.setText(stringArray[1]);
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("2"))
        theOutputLabel.setText(stringArray[2]);
```

You should parse the input and get element from the array according to the index.

```
/** DO THIS */ 

int index = Integer.parseInt(e.getActionCommand());

theOutputLabel.setText(stringArray[index]);
```

`Integer.parseInt()` could throw a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` if the input is not a valid integer, so you have to add a catch for that.

If you want to have the `index` available for test in the `while` condition, then declare it without initializing before the `do` block.

Answer (score 0):

Hey apart from what @isapir has suggested also please check that there are few places in your code that would result into **NullPointerExceptions** like :

```
JTextField inputArea; // Not assigned will lead to NPE
JLabel theOutputLabel; // Not assigned will lead to NPE
String userInput = inputArea.getText(); // Because of inputArea unassigned this line will throw NPE for sure so fix that as well.
```

So I'm assuming what exception you were getting in cmdPrompt would be NPE one so better fix your basic bug first and check your constructor code properly. Lastly, it's always better to share the exception details before post questions on SO.

`e.getActionCommand().equals("0")` this line will not give what you have entered in frame pop-up. Check this also instead use `inputArea.getText()` will give you user's entered number digit.